# how to use longtable with resizebox

Tags: tables, longtable

I have this really huge longtable, in both height (it spans several pages) and width. I want to make my table fit any page width, and so I am thinking of using resizebox. However, it seems that they are not compatible... Can someone help me please?

The code I have is this:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{small}

        \begin{longtable}{llllll}
            \caption{Significant results (p<0.01).}
            \label{table:CTM_results_POAF} \\
            \hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Metrics}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\boldsymbol{\rho}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Controls}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{POAF}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{P-values}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{AUC}} \\ \hline
            \endfirsthead

            \multicolumn{3}{c}%
            {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
            \hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Metrics}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\boldsymbol{\rho}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Controls}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{POAF}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{P-values}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{AUC}} \\ \hline
            \endhead

            \hline \multicolumn{6}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
            \endfoot

            \endlastfoot

            \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{1 hour before POAF} (lag$=5$)}                                                                                                                                                                              \\ \hline
            \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{on RRnorm}}          & 5.0                      & 0.9987 (0.9960 / 0.9993)            & 0.9952 (0.9862 / 0.9982)        & 1.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.76                           \\
            \textbf{PR\textsubscript{off RRnorm}}         & 4.0                      & 0.9982 (0.9934 / 0.9993)            & 0.9914 (0.9811 / 0.9982)        & 5.6$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{PR\textsubscript{on RRnorm}}          & 5.0                      & 0.9988 (0.9960 / 0.9994)            & 0.9954 (0.9838 / 0.9982)        & 6.4$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.79                           \\
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{PR\textsubscript{peak RRnorm}}        & 4.5                   & 0.9986 (0.9958 / 0.9993)            & 0.9931 (0.9856 / 0.9982)        & 6.4$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.79                           \\
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{area}}               & 13.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9999 / 1.0000)        & 1.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.62                           \\
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{dur. RRnorm}}   & 5.0                      & 0.9987 (0.9960 / 0.9993)            & 0.9943 (0.9884 / 0.9982)        & 1.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.77                           \\
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.}}         & 4.0                      & 0.9906 (0.9822 / 0.9930)            & 0.9754 (0.9658 / 0.9834)        & 3.1$\times10^{-5}$                              & 0.85                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{gauss. A}}             & 6.0                      & 0.9981 (0.9958 / 0.9990)            & 0.9947 (0.9907 / 0.9977)        & 3.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{magn.}}               & 4.0                      & 0.9826 (0.9770 / 0.9896)            & 0.9721 (0.9564 / 0.9816)        & 9.2$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.78                           \\
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{area norm.}}         & 4.0                      & 0.9776 (0.9687 / 0.9843)            & 0.9647 (0.9560 / 0.9724)        & 4.8$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.79                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{rms norm.}}          & 5.0                      & 0.9912 (0.9855 / 0.9935)            & 0.9842 (0.9787 / 0.9896)        & 5.0$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{vel. disp.}}          & 4.0                      & 0.9821 (0.9781 / 0.9870)            & 0.9764 (0.9726 / 0.9816)        & 3.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\

            \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{2 hours before POAF} (lag$=8$)}   \\ \hline
            \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{off}}                 & 8.5                   & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9987 / 1.0000)        & 2.8$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.67                           \\
            \textbf{PR\textsubscript{on}}                  & 11.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9992 / 1.0000)        & 5.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.65                           \\
            \textbf{PR\textsubscript{peak}}                & 14.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9991 / 1.0000)        & 5.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.67                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{dur. RRnorm}}   & 7.5                   & 0.9992 (0.9981 / 1.0000)            & 0.9971 (0.9930 / 0.9992)        & 8.8$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.}}         & 4.5                   & 0.9952 (0.9892 / 0.9968)            & 0.9884 (0.9756 / 0.9942)        & 2.8$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.76                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{gauss. C}}             & 14.5                  & 1.0000 (0.9992 / 1.0000)            & 0.9991 (0.9986 / 0.9997)        & 7.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.71                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{area norm.}}         & 3.5                   & 0.9593 (0.9466 / 0.9684)            & 0.9372 (0.9327 / 0.9548)        & 5.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{fin. dur.}}     & 6.0                      & 0.9994 (0.9981 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9998 / 1.0000)        & 2.7$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.75                           \\

            \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{4 hours before POAF} (lag$=6$)}    \\ \hline
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{area}}               & 13.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9995 / 1.0000)        & 1.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.65                           \\
            \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{6 hours before POAF} (lag$=6$)}     \\ \hline
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{energy}}             & 11.5                  & 0.9991 (0.9981 / 0.9997)            & 0.9980 (0.9961 / 0.9987)        & 8.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.}}         & 4.5                   & 0.9941 (0.9895 / 0.9968)            & 0.9911 (0.9816 / 0.9922)        & 4.8$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{fin. dur.}}     & 6.0                      & 0.9993 (0.9976 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9994 / 1.0000)        & 5.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           \\

            \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{12 hours before POAF} (lag$=4$)}    \\ \hline
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{off}}                 & 13.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9990 / 1.0000)        & 5.2$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.65                           \\
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{on}}                  & 7.5                   & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 0.9998 (0.9990 / 1.0000)        & 7.6$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.71                           \\
            \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{level}}                 & 11.0                     & 0.9996 (0.9990 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)        & 6.4$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.70                           \\
            \textbf{PR\textsubscript{off}}                 & 16.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9994 / 1.0000)        & 2.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.62                           \\
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{PR\textsubscript{on}}                  & 8.0                      & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 0.9995 (0.9986 / 1.0000)        & 5.6$\times10^{-5}$                              & 0.75                           \\
            \textbf{PR\textsubscript{peak}}                & 13.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9987 / 1.0000)        & 2.4$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.66                           \\
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{al}}           & 7.0                      & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 0.9998 (0.9997 / 1.0000)        & 6.2$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.70                           \\
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{dur.}}           & 7.0                      & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 0.9998 (0.9997 / 1.0000)        & 6.2$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.70                           \\
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.}}         & 5.0                      & 0.9974 (0.9937 / 0.9990)            & 0.9938 (0.9902 / 0.9953)        & 3.4$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.79                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{magn.}}               & 10.0                     & 0.9996 (0.9989 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)        & 3.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{vel. disp.}}          & 10.5                  & 1.0000 (0.9993 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)        & 8.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.67                           \\

            \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{18 hours before POAF} (lag$=9$)}         \\ \hline
            \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{off}}                 & 9.5                   & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9988 / 1.0000)        & 6.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.63                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{al}}           & 1.0                      & 0.2750 (0.2431 / 0.3175)            & 0.2420 (0.2335 / 0.2543)        & 2.6$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{dur.}}           & 1.0                      & 0.2750 (0.2431 / 0.3175)            & 0.2421 (0.2335 / 0.2543)        & 2.6$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.}}         & 4.0                      & 0.9901 (0.9862 / 0.9931)            & 0.9827 (0.9633 / 0.9870)        & 1.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.76                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{ini. dur.}}     & 2.0                      & 0.6733 (0.6358 / 0.7047)            & 0.6468 (0.6180 / 0.6552)        & 8.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.71                           \\

            \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{24 hours before POAF} (lag$=6$)}        \\ \hline
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{al}}           & 8.0                      & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)        & 4.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.59                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{dur.}}           & 8.0                      & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)        & 4.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.59                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{magn.}}               & 3.0                      & 0.9461 (0.9349 / 0.9627)            & 0.9270 (0.9185 / 0.9405)        & 7.8$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{max. vel.}}           & 3.5                   & 0.9629 (0.9585 / 0.9706)            & 0.9576 (0.9467 / 0.9605)        & 3.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{min. vel.}}           & 3.5                   & 0.9625 (0.9561 / 0.9697)            & 0.9548 (0.9508 / 0.9633)        & 7.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           \\

            \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{30 hours before POAF} (lag$=7$)}          \\ \hline
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{area}}               & 12.5                  & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)        & 8.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.58                           \\
            \textbf{WI$_t$}                        & 9.0                      & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)        & 2.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.61                           \\

            \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{36 hours before POAF} (lag$=3$)}              \\ \hline
            \textbf{CC}                        & 6.0                      & 0.9951 (0.9916 / 0.9973)            & 0.9874 (0.9781 / 0.9940)        & 9.6$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.71                           \\
            \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{on RRnorm}}          & 23.5                  & 0.9993 (0.9989 / 1.0000)            & 0.9987 (0.9972 / 0.9994)        & 5.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
            \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{level}}                 & 6.5                   & 0.9972 (0.9952 / 0.9993)            & 0.9936 (0.9907 / 0.9966)        & 2.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.75                           \\
            \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{level Rnorm}}          & 6.5                   & 0.9972 (0.9951 / 0.9989)            & 0.9950 (0.9911 / 0.9974)        & 9.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.71                           \\
            \textbf{PR\textsubscript{off RRnorm}}         & 23.5                  & 0.9993 (0.9989 / 1.0000)            & 0.9987 (0.9972 / 0.9994)        & 9.6$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.71                           \\
            \textbf{PR\textsubscript{on RRnorm}}          & 25.0                     & 0.9993 (0.9989 / 1.0000)            & 0.9987 (0.9979 / 0.9994)        & 4.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
            \textbf{PR\textsubscript{peak RRnorm}}        & 23.5                  & 0.9993 (0.9989 / 1.0000)            & 0.9987 (0.9972 / 0.9994)        & 5.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{area}}               & 5.5                   & 0.9980 (0.9957 / 0.9993)            & 0.9945 (0.9908 / 0.9983)        & 9.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.71                           \\
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{dur. RRnorm}}   & 23.5                  & 0.9995 (0.9990 / 1.0000)            & 0.9986 (0.9972 / 0.9994)        & 1.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.77                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{area norm.}}         & 4.5                   & 0.9886 (0.9833 / 0.9938)            & 0.9806 (0.9763 / 0.9886)        & 7.7$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           \\

            \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{42 hours before POAF} (lag$=1$)}          \\ \hline
            \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{on}}                  & 3.5                   & 0.9387 (0.9278 / 0.9454)            & 0.9459 (0.9429 / 0.9520)        & 9.6$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{energy norm.}}       & 12.5                     & 0.9993 (0.9986 / 0.9998)            & 0.9982 (0.9973 / 0.9987)        & 1.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.79                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{fin. dur.}}     & 3.5                   & 0.9402 (0.9251 / 0.9537)            & 0.9571 (0.9470 / 0.9654)        & 4.6$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.75                           \\
            \textbf{WI$_t$}                        & 8.0                      & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 0.9998 (0.9997 / 1.0000)        & 9.7$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.68                           \\

            \hline \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{48 hours before POAF} (lag$=7$)} \\ \hline
            \textbf{PQ\textsubscript{level Pnorm}}          & 17.5                  & 0.9982 (0.9975 / 0.9989)            & 0.9993 (0.9989 / 1.0000)        & 3.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.76                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{area}}               & 3.0                      & 0.9181 (0.9010 / 0.9338)            & 0.8926 (0.8859 / 0.9262)        & 9.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{gauss. W}}             & 20.0                     & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9989 / 1.0000)        & 9.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.66                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{magn.}}               & 2.5                   & 0.9210 (0.8766 / 0.9576)            & 0.8810 (0.8358 / 0.9132)        & 7.4$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{area norm.}}         & 2.0                      & 0.8111 (0.7547 / 0.8485)            & 0.7089 (0.6585 / 0.7424)        & 1.5$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.84                           \\
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{rms norm.}}          & 2.0                      & 0.7889 (0.7472 / 0.8466)            & 0.6877 (0.6503 / 0.7236)        & 1.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.79                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{off amp.}}           & 8.0                      & 0.9971 (0.9952 / 0.9986)            & 0.9992 (0.9980 / 1.0000)        & 2.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.77                           \\
            \textbf{P\textsubscript{fin. dur.}}     & 5.5                   & 0.9988 (0.9962 / 0.9995)            & 0.9997 (0.9993 / 1.0000)        & 9.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
            \textbf{WI$_t$}                        & 2.5                   & 0.8301 (0.8163 / 0.8425)            & 0.8083 (0.8008 / 0.8246)        & 3.7$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.76         \\ \hline                 




        \end{longtable}
    \end{small}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Don't use `\resizebox` for elements that contain text. Choose a smaller font size instead or rearrange your table .

Comment: How can I adjust font size (instead of using things like `\tiny`) only for this particular table?

Comment: `\begingroup\fontsize{<size>}{<baselineskip>}\selectfont<your table>\endgroup`

Comment: @DiogoTec What Skillmon said. Alternatively you could place your table on landscape pages

Comment: Yeah, that's not an option because it would take me like 10 pages :( Isn't it possible to use resizebox? I just want it to make the job, even though it's not recommended lol

Comment: `\resizebox` leads to inconsistent font sizes; possible so small that no one will want to read  it.

Comment: you could just change `small` that you have to `footnotesize or `tiny` never put tables in resizebox, even when they do not give tex errors the result will bepoor. Also do not put longtable in a center environment (it has no affect on the horizontal position of the table)

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}

{\small\tabcolsep=3pt  % hold it local
\begin{longtable}{ >{\bfseries\footnotesize}llllll }
\caption{Significant results (p<0.01).}\label{table:CTM_results_POAF} \\\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Metrics}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\boldsymbol{\rho}$} & 
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Controls}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{POAF}} & 
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{P-values}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{AUC}} \\ \midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}%
            {\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page} \\
            \midrule \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Metrics}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\boldsymbol{\rho}$} 
            & 
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Controls}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{POAF}} & 
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{P-values}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{AUC}} \\ \midrule
\endhead            
\midrule\multicolumn{6}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \midrule
\endfoot    
\bottomrule     
\endlastfoot        
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{1 hour before POAF} (lag$=5$)}\\ \midrule
PQ\textsubscript{on RRnorm}          & 5.0                      & 0.9987 
            (0.9960 / 0.9993)            & 0.9952 (0.9862 / 0.9982)        & 
            1.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.76                           \\
            PR\textsubscript{off RRnorm}         & 4.0                      & 0.9982 
            (0.9934 / 0.9993)            & 0.9914 (0.9811 / 0.9982)        & 
            5.6$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            PR\textsubscript{on RRnorm}          & 5.0                      & 0.9988 
            (0.9960 / 0.9994)            & 0.9954 (0.9838 / 0.9982)        & 
            6.4$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.79                           \\
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            PR\textsubscript{peak RRnorm}        & 4.5                   & 0.9986 (0.9958 
            / 0.9993)            & 0.9931 (0.9856 / 0.9982)        & 
            6.4$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.79                           \\
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            P\textsubscript{area}               & 13.0                     & 1.0000 
            (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9999 / 1.0000)        & 
            1.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.62                           \\
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            P\textsubscript{dur. RRnorm}   & 5.0                      & 0.9987 (0.9960 / 
            0.9993)            & 0.9943 (0.9884 / 0.9982)        & 
            1.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.77                           \\
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.}         & 4.0                      & 0.9906 
            (0.9822 / 0.9930)            & 0.9754 (0.9658 / 0.9834)        & 
            3.1$\times10^{-5}$                              & 0.85                           \\
            P\textsubscript{gauss. A}             & 6.0                      & 0.9981 
            (0.9958 / 0.9990)            & 0.9947 (0.9907 / 0.9977)        & 
            3.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            P\textsubscript{magn.}               & 4.0                      & 0.9826 
            (0.9770 / 0.9896)            & 0.9721 (0.9564 / 0.9816)        & 
            9.2$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.78                           \\
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            P\textsubscript{area norm.}         & 4.0                      & 0.9776 
            (0.9687 / 0.9843)            & 0.9647 (0.9560 / 0.9724)        & 
            4.8$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.79                           \\
            P\textsubscript{rms norm.}          & 5.0                      & 0.9912 
            (0.9855 / 0.9935)            & 0.9842 (0.9787 / 0.9896)        & 
            5.0$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
            P\textsubscript{vel. disp.}          & 4.0                      & 0.9821 
            (0.9781 / 0.9870)            & 0.9764 (0.9726 / 0.9816)        & 
            3.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\

            \midrule \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{2 hours before POAF} (lag$=8$)}   \\ \midrule
            PQ\textsubscript{off}                 & 8.5                   & 1.0000 (1.0000 
            / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9987 / 1.0000)        & 
            2.8$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.67                           \\
            PR\textsubscript{on}                  & 11.0                     & 1.0000 
            (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9992 / 1.0000)        & 
            5.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.65                           \\
            PR\textsubscript{peak}                & 14.0                     & 1.0000 
            (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9991 / 1.0000)        & 
            5.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.67                           \\
            P\textsubscript{dur. RRnorm}   & 7.5                   & 0.9992 (0.9981 / 
            1.0000)            & 0.9971 (0.9930 / 0.9992)        & 
            8.8$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           \\
            P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.}         & 4.5                   & 0.9952 (0.9892 
            / 0.9968)            & 0.9884 (0.9756 / 0.9942)        & 
            2.8$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.76                           \\
            P\textsubscript{gauss. C}             & 14.5                  & 1.0000 (0.9992 
            / 1.0000)            & 0.9991 (0.9986 / 0.9997)        & 
            7.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.71                           \\
            P\textsubscript{area norm.}         & 3.5                   & 0.9593 (0.9466 / 
            0.9684)            & 0.9372 (0.9327 / 0.9548)        & 
            5.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
            P\textsubscript{fin. dur.}     & 6.0                      & 0.9994 (0.9981 / 
            1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9998 / 1.0000)        & 
            2.7$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.75                           \\

            \midrule \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{4 hours before POAF} (lag$=6$)}    \\ \midrule
            P\textsubscript{area}               & 13.0                     & 1.0000 
            (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9995 / 1.0000)        & 
            1.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.65                           \\
            \midrule \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{6 hours before POAF} (lag$=6$)}     \\ \midrule
            P\textsubscript{energy}             & 11.5                  & 0.9991 (0.9981 / 
            0.9997)            & 0.9980 (0.9961 / 0.9987)        & 
            8.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           \\
            P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.}         & 4.5                   & 0.9941 (0.9895 
            / 0.9968)            & 0.9911 (0.9816 / 0.9922)        & 
            4.8$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
            P\textsubscript{fin. dur.}     & 6.0                      & 0.9993 (0.9976 / 
            1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9994 / 1.0000)        & 
            5.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           \\

            \midrule \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{12 hours before POAF} (lag$=4$)}    \\ \midrule
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            PQ\textsubscript{off}                 & 13.0                     & 1.0000 
            (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9990 / 1.0000)        & 
            5.2$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.65                           \\
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            PQ\textsubscript{on}                  & 7.5                   & 1.0000 (1.0000 
            / 1.0000)            & 0.9998 (0.9990 / 1.0000)        & 
            7.6$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.71                           \\
            PQ\textsubscript{level}                 & 11.0                     & 0.9996 
            (0.9990 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)        & 
            6.4$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.70                           \\
            PR\textsubscript{off}                 & 16.0                     & 1.0000 
            (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9994 / 1.0000)        & 
            2.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.62                           \\
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            PR\textsubscript{on}                  & 8.0                      & 1.0000 
            (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 0.9995 (0.9986 / 1.0000)        & 
            5.6$\times10^{-5}$                              & 0.75                           \\
            PR\textsubscript{peak}                & 13.0                     & 1.0000 
            (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9987 / 1.0000)        & 
            2.4$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.66                           \\
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            P\textsubscript{al}           & 7.0                      & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 
            1.0000)            & 0.9998 (0.9997 / 1.0000)        & 
            6.2$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.70                           \\
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            P\textsubscript{dur.}           & 7.0                      & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 
            1.0000)            & 0.9998 (0.9997 / 1.0000)        & 
            6.2$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.70                           \\
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.}         & 5.0                      & 0.9974 
            (0.9937 / 0.9990)            & 0.9938 (0.9902 / 0.9953)        & 
            3.4$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.79                           \\
            P\textsubscript{magn.}               & 10.0                     & 0.9996 
            (0.9989 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)        & 
            3.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           \\
            P\textsubscript{vel. disp.}          & 10.5                  & 1.0000 (0.9993 
            / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)        & 
            8.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.67                           \\

            \midrule \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{18 hours before POAF} (lag$=9$)}         \\ \midrule
            PQ\textsubscript{off}                 & 9.5                   & 1.0000 (1.0000 
            / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9988 / 1.0000)        & 
            6.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.63                           \\
            P\textsubscript{al}           & 1.0                      & 0.2750 (0.2431 / 
            0.3175)            & 0.2420 (0.2335 / 0.2543)        & 
            2.6$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
            P\textsubscript{dur.}           & 1.0                      & 0.2750 (0.2431 / 
            0.3175)            & 0.2421 (0.2335 / 0.2543)        & 
            2.6$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            P\textsubscript{eucl. dist.}         & 4.0                      & 0.9901 
            (0.9862 / 0.9931)            & 0.9827 (0.9633 / 0.9870)        & 
            1.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.76                           \\
            P\textsubscript{ini. dur.}     & 2.0                      & 0.6733 (0.6358 / 
            0.7047)            & 0.6468 (0.6180 / 0.6552)        & 
            8.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.71                           \\

            \midrule \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{24 hours before POAF} (lag$=6$)}        \\ \midrule
            P\textsubscript{al}           & 8.0                      & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 
            1.0000)            & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)        & 
            4.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.59                           \\
            P\textsubscript{dur.}           & 8.0                      & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 
            1.0000)            & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)        & 
            4.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.59                           \\
            P\textsubscript{magn.}               & 3.0                      & 0.9461 
            (0.9349 / 0.9627)            & 0.9270 (0.9185 / 0.9405)        & 
            7.8$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           \\
            P\textsubscript{max. vel.}           & 3.5                   & 0.9629 (0.9585 
            / 0.9706)            & 0.9576 (0.9467 / 0.9605)        & 
            3.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
            P\textsubscript{min. vel.}           & 3.5                   & 0.9625 (0.9561 
            / 0.9697)            & 0.9548 (0.9508 / 0.9633)        & 
            7.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           
            \\\midrule 
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{30 hours before POAF} (lag$=7$)}          \\ \midrule
P\textsubscript{area}  & 12.5 & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000) & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000) & 
            8.3$\times10^{-3}$ & 0.58 \\
            WI$_t$                        & 9.0                      & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 
            1.0000)            & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 1.0000)        & 
            2.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.61                           \\
            \midrule \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{36 hours before POAF} (lag$=3$)}              \\ 
            \midrule
            CC                       & 6.0                      & 0.9951 (0.9916 / 
            0.9973)            & 0.9874 (0.9781 / 0.9940)        & 
            9.6$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.71                           \\
            PQ\textsubscript{on RRnorm}          & 23.5                  & 0.9993 (0.9989 
            / 1.0000)            & 0.9987 (0.9972 / 0.9994)        & 
            5.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
            PQ\textsubscript{level}                 & 6.5                   & 0.9972 
            (0.9952 / 0.9993)            & 0.9936 (0.9907 / 0.9966)        & 
            2.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.75                           \\
            PQ\textsubscript{level Rnorm}          & 6.5                   & 0.9972 
            (0.9951 / 0.9989)            & 0.9950 (0.9911 / 0.9974)        & 
            9.5$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.71                           \\
            PR\textsubscript{off RRnorm}         & 23.5                  & 0.9993 (0.9989 
            / 1.0000)            & 0.9987 (0.9972 / 0.9994)        & 
            9.6$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.71                           \\
            PR\textsubscript{on RRnorm}          & 25.0                     & 0.9993 
            (0.9989 / 1.0000)            & 0.9987 (0.9979 / 0.9994)        & 
            4.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
            PR\textsubscript{peak RRnorm}        & 23.5                  & 0.9993 (0.9989 
            / 1.0000)            & 0.9987 (0.9972 / 0.9994)        & 
            5.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
            P\textsubscript{area}               & 5.5                   & 0.9980 (0.9957 / 
            0.9993)            & 0.9945 (0.9908 / 0.9983)        & 
            9.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.71                           \\
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            P\textsubscript{dur. RRnorm}   & 23.5                  & 0.9995 (0.9990 / 
            1.0000)            & 0.9986 (0.9972 / 0.9994)        & 
            1.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.77                           \\
            P\textsubscript{area norm.}         & 4.5                   & 0.9886 (0.9833 / 
            0.9938)            & 0.9806 (0.9763 / 0.9886)        & 
            7.7$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.72                           \\

            \midrule \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{42 hours before POAF} (lag$=1$)}          \\ 
            \midrule
            PQ\textsubscript{on}                  & 3.5                   & 0.9387 (0.9278 
            / 0.9454)            & 0.9459 (0.9429 / 0.9520)        & 
            9.6$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            P\textsubscript{energy norm.}       & 12.5                     & 0.9993 
            (0.9986 / 0.9998)            & 0.9982 (0.9973 / 0.9987)        & 
            1.1$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.79                           \\
            P\textsubscript{fin. dur.}     & 3.5                   & 0.9402 (0.9251 / 
            0.9537)            & 0.9571 (0.9470 / 0.9654)        & 
            4.6$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.75                           \\
            WI$_t$                        & 8.0                      & 1.0000 (1.0000 / 
            1.0000)            & 0.9998 (0.9997 / 1.0000)        & 
            9.7$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.68                           \\

            \midrule \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{48 hours before POAF} (lag$=7$)} \\ \midrule
            PQ\textsubscript{level Pnorm}          & 17.5                  & 0.9982 
            (0.9975 / 0.9989)            & 0.9993 (0.9989 / 1.0000)        & 
            3.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.76                           \\
            P\textsubscript{area}               & 3.0                      & 0.9181 
            (0.9010 / 0.9338)            & 0.8926 (0.8859 / 0.9262)        & 
            9.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
            P\textsubscript{gauss. W}             & 20.0                     & 1.0000 
            (1.0000 / 1.0000)            & 1.0000 (0.9989 / 1.0000)        & 
            9.9$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.66                           \\
            P\textsubscript{magn.}               & 2.5                   & 0.9210 (0.8766 
            / 0.9576)            & 0.8810 (0.8358 / 0.9132)        & 
            7.4$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.74                           \\
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            P\textsubscript{area norm.}         & 2.0                      & 0.8111 
            (0.7547 / 0.8485)            & 0.7089 (0.6585 / 0.7424)        & 
            1.5$\times10^{-4}$                              & 0.84                           \\
            \rowcolor[HTML]{efefef} 
            P\textsubscript{rms norm.}          & 2.0                      & 0.7889 
            (0.7472 / 0.8466)            & 0.6877 (0.6503 / 0.7236)        & 
            1.2$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.79                           \\
            P\textsubscript{off amp.}           & 8.0                      & 0.9971 
            (0.9952 / 0.9986)            & 0.9992 (0.9980 / 1.0000)        & 
            2.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.77                           \\
            P\textsubscript{fin. dur.}     & 5.5                   & 0.9988 (0.9962 / 
            0.9995)            & 0.9997 (0.9993 / 1.0000)        & 
            9.3$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.73                           \\
            WI$_t$                        & 2.5                   & 0.8301 (0.8163 / 
            0.8425)            & 0.8083 (0.8008 / 0.8246)        & 
            3.7$\times10^{-3}$                              & 0.76         \\ 
\end{longtable}
}% end

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what have you used/done?

Comment: The important lines are: `{\small\tabcolsep=3pt  % hold it local
\begin{longtable}{ >{\bfseries\footnotesize}llllll }`